# scala check if at least one case class field value is nonEmpty using reflection

Tags: scala, validation, reflection, option-type, case-class

I have a requirement that for a given case class with around 30+ Option[T] fields needs to have at least 1 field nonEmpty in order to be valid.
Instead of checking each field individually I opted for checking all fields via reflection in a generic way. The code I came up with (based on some other answers in SO as well) was:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

  // gets all methods of a Case Class
  def getMethods[T: ru.TypeTag] = typeOf[T].members.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
  }.toList


  /**
    *  Returns the value of all Case Class fields
    * @param obj case class object
    * @return a Sequence of all field values
    */
  def getAllCaseClassFieldValues[T: ru.TypeTag](obj: Object): Seq[Any] = {
    val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    getMethods[T].map(m => mirror.reflect(obj).reflectField(m).get)
  }
```

The case class:

```
case class SampleRequest(field1: Option[String], field2: Option[String], //.... up to 30 or more fields
```

The code that checks to see if at least 1 is nonEmpty:

```
 val fieldValues = getAllCaseClassFieldValues[SampleRequest](r)
 val noneCount = fieldValues.count(_ == None)
 val atLeastOneNonEmpty = noneCount < fieldValues.size
```

I was wondering if there would be a better way for validating this via reflection or other mechanism?

Answer (score 10):

It's a case class so it implements the Product trait.  The Product trait has an iterator `def productIterator : Iterator[Any]`

```
case class Foo(one: Option[Int], two: Option[String], three : Option[Double])

var i = Foo(None, Some("Woot!"), None)
var j = Foo(Some(1), Some("There Can Be Only"), None)
var k = Foo(None, None, None)

i.productIterator.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Some[_]]) // True
j.productIterator.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Some[_]]) // True
k.productIterator.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Some[_]]) // False
```

I use this trick all the time when evaluating sparsely populated streaming data.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
abstract class AtLeastOneNonEmptyOption[T] { self: T with Product =>

  def nonEmpty: Boolean = this.productIterator.exists {
    case Some(_) => true
    case _ => false
  }

}

case class MyClass(foo: Option[String], bar: Option[Int]) extends AtLeastOneNonEmptyOption[MyClass]

val nonEmptyClass = MyClass(Some("foo"), None)
val emptyClass = MyClass(None, None)

nonEmptyClass.nonEmpty //true
emptyClass.nonEmpty //false
```

There may be a better way.